# Provider across routes but after MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a class which needs access to `MaterialApp` `context`, but it also needs global access from all routes.

To create a global provider, I can wrap `MaterialApp` with `Provider`, but such provider has no access to the `context`. Therefore, I have to provide the class after `MaterialApp`.

I realize I could wrap every single route with the provider because it is stateless, but I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `builder` or `onGenerateRoute` of `MaterialApp`

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Provider.value(
       value: // TO-DO use context
      child: child, 
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the material app in a Builder to gain acess do a brand new context.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on "gain access to a brand new context"? Thanks!